# How to check null condition for the boolean variable

Tags: java

I have a class as shown

```
package com;

public class Person {
boolean registered;

public boolean isRegistered() {
    return registered;
}

public void setRegistered(boolean registered) {
    this.registered = registered;
}
}
```

The Data to Person Object will be set based on the Data present in DB . 
The problem is that for older records the registered filed is not present .

so i how can i test if the filed is present or not ??

package com;

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person per = new Person();

        if (per.isRegistered()) {

        }
    }

}
```

How can i check if the per.isRegistered() field is present or not for that Person Object  ??

Comment: You could always just default the registered boolean to false since if the field is not set, you could assume it's not registered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boolean` is primitive data type which can not be null, only can be true or false. But `Boolean` Object which is rapper of boolean data type, It could be null and `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE`;

```
public class Person {
    Boolean registered;
    ...
}
```

...

```
Person per = new Person();

if (per.isRegistered()!=null ) {
    if(!per.isRegistered()){
         ...
    }else{
         ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The way your `Person` class is currently defined, you can't, because `boolean` (the primitive type) has no `null` value, only `true` and `false`.

You *could* use `Boolean` (the object equivalent), which can be `null`, `Boolean.TRUE`, or `Boolean.FALSE`.

But more likely you want to solve this at a deeper level. You've said you have data in your database for which this field isn't present. Are those records considered registered or not? Your class should reflect the answer to that question.

Comment: The way it usually happens in practice, the answer is context-dependent and is not a property of the class. Business logic is usually best done with a clean separation of code and data.

Answer (score 3):

`boolean` *can't* be `null`; you'd need to use (`Boolean)` or construct a composite type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Boolean` (capital B) class which allows `NULL` values for references of its kind.

Alternatively, you can use an `enum` having three possible values: `NOT_AVAILABLE`, `YES`, `NO`. This has a clearer semantics and allows you to add other possible values later (if needed).

Answer (score 1):

You need a three state boolean; true, false and not there.

You can achieve this by using Boolean class instead of the primitive boolean and use null as the "not there" indicator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what is on your mind. But if you want to handle a boolean whose values can be one of the following {true/false/null}, you should use a `Boolean` object with is a simple `boolean` wrapper, but it can take the `null` value (as every Java Object can be set to null).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

```
if (Optional.ofNullable(per.isRegistered()).orElse(false)) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I think this will be very helpful or easy.

Answer (score 0):

`boolean registered` as field it's false by default. Moreover `boolean` not related to `Object` class but primitive value so can't be `null` at all.

Only one Null-pointer you may get here it's when `per` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Make the column nullable and use a Boolean instead of boolean. For the specific problem though, I think you can assume that if it is null the user is not registered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the person class to use it in the test class.
You also have to define the boolean.